# MySQL Workbench don't connect in localhost (Ubuntu 21.10)

Tags: mysql, connection, mysql-workbench

MySQL community server is already running, the system is updated, when I ping localhost in the port 3306 it responds back, I tried to change the user from root to my personal user ( that has sudo privilleges) and it didn't work and I can't set a password (other error message)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY0c8.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ucck.png)

Answer (score 0):

1.mysql -uroot -p

2.select user,host from mysql.user;

3.create user xxx and grant all privileges on *.* to xxx

4.flush privileges;

5.commit;

Comment: thanks bro, after I reinstalled I did this configuration and worked